# How to write a shell script creating users and generating random password for them

Tags: shell

I am trying to create 3 users with random password each. I am new to shell scripting and nt sure if I have written the best script to achieve this. Kindly help me check. Thank you

```
#!/bin/bash
  
function create_user() {
    user_name=$1
    password=$(pwgen 5 1)

    sudo apt install pwgen
    sudo useradd $user_name
    sudo pwgen 5 1
    sudo chmod u+x homework.sh
    sudo grep -i $user_name /etc/passwd

    echo "User $user_name created with password $password"

}

create_user adam
create_user bety
create_user carl
```

Comment: What is the question here?  If it meets your requirements, it is ok.  Move on :)  You can check bash syntax on https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Yes it is okay. I have made some modifications though by moving "sudo apt install pwgen" out of the function definition and placed it above it so it does not carry it out each time the function is called. Thanks for your response @Nic3500